# python dictionary check if any key other than given keys exist

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary that specifies some properties for a package:

`d = {'from': 'Bob', 'to': 'Joe', 'item': 'book', 'weight': '3.5lbs'}`

To check the validity of a package dictionary, it needs to have a `'from'` and `'to'` key, and any number of properties, but there must be at least one property. So a dictionary can have either `'item'` or `'weight'`, both, but can't have neither. The property keys could be anything, not limited to `'item'` or `'weight'`.

How would I check dictionaries to make sure they're valid, as in having the `'to'`, `'from'`, and at least one other key?

The only method I can think of is by obtaining `d.keys()`, removing the `'from'` and `'to'` keys, and checking if its empty.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: You can try like this - if len(d.keys()) > 2 and 'from' and 'to' in d.keys():

Comment: Then I don't know if dictionaries are the ideal data structure in this instance

Comment: What would you suggest as a more ideal data structure? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a class so that you could make objects for these bundles. Your constructor could force set `to`, `from` and require an additional attribute to be set

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
must = {"from", "to"}
print len(d) > len(must) and all(key in d for key in must)
# True
```

This solution makes sure that your dictionary has more elements than the elements in the `must` set and also all the elements in `must` will be there in the dictionary.

The advantage of this solution is that, it is easily extensible. If you want to make sure that one more parameter exists in the dictionary, just include that in the `must` dictionary, it will work fine. You don't have to alter the logic.

**Edit**

Apart from that, if you are using Python 2.7, you can do this more succinctly like this

```
print d.viewkeys() > {"from", "to"}
```

If you are using Python 3.x, you can simply write that as

```
print(d.keys() > {"from", "to"})
```

This hack works because, `d.viewkeys` and `d.keys` return set-like objects. So, we can use set comparison operators. `>` is used to check if the left hand side set is a strict superset of the right hand side set. So, in order to satisfy the condition, the left hand side set-like object should have both `from` and `to`, and some other object.

Quoting from the [`set.issuperset` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset),

> #### set > other
>
> Test whether the set is a proper superset of other, that is, `set >= other and set != other`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said the optional keys could be anything, not limited to item or weight.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal Please check the updated answer, does this look fine to you.

Comment: `len(d) > len(must) and must.issubset(d)`

Comment: Wow, I really liked `print {"from", "to"} < set(d.viewkeys())`. Thanks!

Comment: @Veedrac We don't have to check the length, if we can check if it is a strict subset.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yep, but I was trying to avoid the `set` call which in theory is quite suboptimal, so I rewrote the first answer.

Comment: @Veedrac Mmmm, I added an alternate to that also, does that look okay? :)

Comment: Why not just `{"from", "to"} < set(d)`? The reason to avoid the `set` call was 'cause it was `O(n)`, not 'cause it was ugly.

Comment: @Veedrac Oh yeah, that looks better. Thanks :) Included that in the answer. But, apart from `d.viewkeys() | {}`, everything else which use `set` will be `O(N)` I guess.

Comment: `d.viewkeys() | {}` is still `O(n)`, although I'm not sure if that's what you just wrote.

Comment: @Veedrac Okay, it is weird. Check the updated answer. This doesn't need the `set` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

if `d.keys()` has a length of at least 3, and it has a from and to attribute, you're golden.

My knowledge of Python isn't the greatest but I imagine it goes something like `if len(d.keys) > 2 and d['from'] and d['to']`

Comment: Couldn't it potentially have `from` `item` and `weight` which is not golden?

Comment: My second constraint requires both a `from` and a `to`.

Comment: d['from'] will throw an error if the attribute does not exist

Comment: If it throws an error, then it is as easy as checking another way. The logic is correct though. Like I said, I'm not a Python expert, but this is more about the logic than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
def exists(var, dict):
    try:
        x = dict[var]
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False

def check(dict):
    if exists('from', dict) == False:
        return False
    if exists('to', dict) == False:
        return False
    if exists('item', dict) == False and exists('weight', dict) == False:
        return False
    return True

def main():
    d = {'from': 'Bob', 'to': 'Joe', 'item': 'book', 'weight': '3.5lbs'}
    mybool = check(d)
    print mybool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like this is overkill. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address the problem OP has, but provides what I think to be a better practice solution. I realize there's already been an answer but I just spent a few minutes reading on best practices and thought I would share

Problems with using a dictionary:

- Dictionaries are meant to be on a key value basis. You inherently have 2 different types of key values given that `to` and `from` are mandatory while `item` and `weight` are optional
- Dictionaries are meant to be logic-less. By setting certain requirements, you violate the principal of a dictionary which is just meant to hold data. To make a instance you need to build some sort of logic constructor for the dictionary

So why not just use a class? Proposed alternative:

```
class D(dict): # inheirits dict
   def __init__ (self,t,f,**attributes): # from is a keyword
       self['to'] = t
       self['from'] = f

       if(len(attributes) > 0):
           self.update(attributes)
       else:
           raise Exception("Require attribute")

d = D('jim','bob',item='book')
print d # {'to': 'jim', 'from': 'bob', 'item': 'book'}
print d['to'] # jim
print d['item'] # item
print d['from'] # bob

d = D('jim','bob') # throws error
```

Obviously this falls apart if `to` and `from` are set asynchronously but I think the base idea still holds. Creating a class also gives you the verbosity to prevent `to` and `from` from being overwritten/deleted as well as limiting the minimum/maximum of attributes set.

Comment: Hmm, an interesting solution, thanks! Unfortunately looking at the code I am working with right now, implementing that class would involve a lot of refactoring. But it seems like a logical solution. I shall look into implementing it in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Since it inherits from dictionary all dictionary methods are preserved, but I do know the pains of refactoring. Best of luck